# Rails: How to pass params with a plus sign from url to controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, parameters, pg-search

I'm on rails and using the `pg_search` gem.
The search works fine when I'm using an input to pass the param. But when I try to pass the query param from url to my controller to do some advanced filtering, it fails.
The url is something like `http://localhost:3000/search?q=new+year`, and my controller reads `params[:q]` as `new` instead of `new year`. I've been reading the doc and googling for hours but cannot find a solution to my problem.
How can I pass the param with a plus sign from url to controller?

Edit: I pass the param as a hidden field using a form. In my view file:

```
  <% if params[:q] %>
    <input name="q" type="hidden" value=<%= params[:q] %>>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: `params` decodes queries correctly; I just tested it on a few of my Rails apps to be absolutely sure. Is it possible that the issue is somewhere else in the controller?

Comment: If you are using a form then it should escape the '+' sign on its own. If you are assembling the url from javascript or something else then you need to escape it manually i.e. "http://localhost:3000/search?q=new%2Byear"

Comment: Yes, you are right. I pass it with a form. I've updated my question with the codes in my view file. I don't know whether it's a good practice to pass the param this way, but I can't find a way to read the current param directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Rails and parameter parsing; you're producing malformed HTML. The problem is that you're missing quotes around your the value of the `value` attribute of your hidden `<input>`.

This:

```
value=<%= params[:q] %>>
```

needs to be this:

```
value="<%= params[:q] %>">
```

Otherwise you're producing something like `<input ... value=new year />` where "year" isn't parsed as part of the `value` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't build a tag like that. Instead use the built-in Rails input tag helpers.

For example:

```
<% if params[:q] %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :q, :value => params[:q] %>
<% end %>
```